# how to insert autoNumbersCode into another table

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables with some fields like this:

```
CompanyTable (companyCode, name, contactCode)
ContactTable (contactCode, address, phone)
```

CompanyTable.contactCode is foregin key that assign to `ContactTable.contactCode`

and also `CompanyTable.companyCode` and `CompanyTable.contactCode` are autoNumbers.

when I insert new record in contactTable, I want to insert it's contactCode into CompanyTable.contactCode like this:

```
insert into contactTable ( address, phone) values ('x', 'x')

update companyTable set company.contactCode = ---------
```

How to get latest identity value after insert query?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@@IDENTITY` to retrieve latest generated Identity value.

execute it after your insert query.

```
insert into contactTable ( address, phone) values ('x', 'x')

DECLARE @contactCode INT;
SELECT @contactCode = @@IDENTITY;
update companyTable set company.contactCode = @contactCode Where companyCode=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a trigger to add the contactCode.  It would look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgUpdateCompanyTable
   ON  dbo.ContactTable
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @id INTEGER

    SET @id = (SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('ContactTable'))

    INSERT INTO CompanyTable (contactCode)
    VALUES (@id)

END
GO
```